# Updating or Adding a Child Record on an Existing Row in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an existing row in SQL called OrderLine.  This links (but does not have to) OrderLineCustomFields. An OrderLine can be inserted with no OrderLineCustomFields object but could have OrderLineCustomFields at a later date.  I don't receive any errors but when the OrderLine is saved, the generated column (OrderLineCustomFields_OrderLineCustomFieldsId) doesn't get stamped with the new ID created thus I have no link between the 2 tables.

If I create a new OrderLine (not an existing row), everything is inserting correctly.

```
public class OrderLine
{
        public int OrderLineId { get; set; }
        public virtual OrderLineCustomFields OrderLineCustomFields { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineCustomFields
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int OrderLineCustomFieldsId { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Sample New object:

```
var ol = new OrderLine();
ol.OrderLineId = 1;
ol.OrderLineCustomFields = new OrderLineCustomFields();
ol.OrderLineCustomFields.SomeValue = "NewValue";
```

Repository code:

```
var olEntity = context.OrderLines?
                .Where(x => x.OrderLineId == ol.OrderLineId)
                .FirstOrDefault();


var olCustomEntity = context.OrderLineCustomFields?
                .Where(x => ol.OrderLineCustomFields.OrderLineCustomFieldsId == x.OrderLineCustomFieldsId)
                .FirstOrDefault();

if (olCustomEntity == null)  //if there isn't a record already, then add it.
{
    context.Entry(ol.OrderLineCustomFields).State = EntityState.Added;
}
else  //else, update the record with new data
{
    ol.OrderLineCustomFields.OrderLineCustomFieldsId = olCustomEntity.OrderLineCustomFieldsId;
    context.Entry(olCustomEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(ol.OrderLineCustomFields);
}

//Save the orderLine
context.Entry(olEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(ol);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Don't you need OrderLineId as foreign key on OrderLineCustomFields?

Comment: @BenPhung Not according to MS with a 1 to 1.  EF creates a column in (SQL) OrderLine as OrderLineCustomFields_OrderLineCustomFieldsId by default which is supposed to get stamped with the ID of OrderLineCustomFields once its inserted.  Again, if I create a new OrderLine that has OrderLineCustomFields, this all works fine (all IDs get populated).  If I need to update an OrderLine with a new OrderLineCustomFields, this doesn't happen.  The id column is null.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working.  I didn't let EF know that the OrderLine was modified:

```
context.Entry(olEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```